# Proof on Prime Numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Show that for any prime numbers p, q, r , one has

the sum of p^2 and q^2 is not equal to r^2

How do i go about doing this question? Do I use mathematical induction or is there any other way to go about doing it? if i use mathematical induction, how do i set the induction statement? because there are three variables p,q and r. Stuck here and hope to get some help. thank you :)